# Batch Aspect Ratio 1:1

Tags: batch

I'm in need of a program that will batch out an aspect ratio of 1:1. 
I was able to use XnView to batch crop the white space out of my image. (example below)

[image]

I need the images in a perfect square.  (example below)

[image]

It would also be helpful to be able to add some padding.

Are there any programs out there that will do that?

I found somewhere that said you could go to edit/set selection ratio inside XnView but can’t find it. The post was from 2008 so i’m sure they’ve updated the program since then.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), a sort of swiss army knife for image processing on the command line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about photography.

Answer (score 1):

With XNview MP:

1. Select images
2. Tools->Batch Convert (or Ctrl+U)
3. on tab Action select Resize
4. Mode - Fit
5. Select Width and Height
6. Unselect "Keep ratio"
7. Enlarge/Reduce - Reduce only
8. press Convert